# colors.xml: Error: Unsupported type 'component' (Android studio)

Tags: android, xml

After the creation of a new project, I get an error with the colors.xml file (more details here: [Error on first build after creating a project: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875744/error-on-first-build-after-creating-a-project-xml-document-structures-must-star)) I "fixed" the colors.xml file and now I get this new error:

```
colors.xml: Error: Unsupported type 'component'
```

The colors.xml file looks like this:

```
<application>
    <component name="PropertiesComponent">
        <property name="ATTACHED_TOOL_WINDOW.DEFAULT.NELE_EDITOR.COMPONENT_TREE.AUTO_HIDE" value="false" />
        <property name="ATTACHED_TOOL_WINDOW.DEFAULT"/>
    </component>
</application>
```

I havent done anything in the android project, I just created it and the first build does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: <component> tag is wrong, it is not supported. remove this tag

Comment: i also have same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Component` tag in a Color resource file.

Here is an example of colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Now I get the following error: "Android resource compilation failed"

Comment: Where is located your colors.xml ? it should be located here `src/main/res/values`

Comment: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\manol\Documents\_docs\programacion\android\MentalPower\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Comment: Not related to colors.xml... Check your `ic_launcher_round.xml` file instead

Comment: It is empty, what should it have?

Comment: Seriously? I suggest you to recreate a new project. I think something get wrong the first time

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but also something similar in several files of the project every time i open a new project. I followed something that someone (can't remember the name) answer in another question:

1.- go to your user folder -->androidStudio folder --> System folder
2.- delete the caches folder

After that the error haven't came back. Hope this help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#79302a</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#561e1c</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#345f41</color>
</resources>
```

This is what a colors.xml looks like. See if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Ohh I too faced similar problems after upgrading studio to 3.2.1

many issues from different files while creating new project:

1. colors.xml
2. ic_launcher_round.xml - mipmap
3. ic_launcher_background.xml - drawable

I tried to change these but nothing worked, changing one is causing other issue.

Finally i have uninstalled 3.2.1 studio version and downloaded 3.1.4(android-studio-ide-173.4907809-windows.exe (828632688 bytes)) from here https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

and finally everything worked fine.
Still i don't know is this an issue from 3.2.1 studio version.

Note: It's basically downgrading studio version :) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It may be which browser you got the install file from.

I just had a student with the same problem (version 3.3 now), and it appears to have been fixed by having him install from a file downloaded with Chrome rather than with Edge. Did you originally install with an install file obtained using Edge?

Comment: Jep I am pretty sure I used chrome, don't really use edge to be honest