# Strange error in colors.xml file in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, gradle

I've been searching for a solution for this but nobody actually can confirm ... when creating new android studio project

> "colors.xml:9:18: Error: XML document structures must start and end
>   within the same entity."

I open that colors.xml it contains some wierd stuff :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
    <component name="AndroidLayouts">
        <shared>
            <config />
        </shared>
    </component>
    <component name="AndroidLogFilters">
        <option n
```

and YES that is the full file ... it's not my first project and i know that's not how the file should look , even if I replaced the content with the correct syntax , many error of the same type in other files as well ,
so my question is , why is this happening ? 
I tried clearing caches of android and deleted the cache of gradle entirely ...nothing seems to work , what could be the problem ? how this file even gets created in the first place ? is it a gradle problem ?

Comment: If that's in your resource folder, then just delete it. I could be wrong but it looks like a copy & paste mistake.

Comment: i said it's a new project , i didn't change anything ... @Aaron

Comment: The xml is malformed and incomplete, it's likely causing the issue

Comment: So? It certainly doesn't look right, the xml is incomplete and no colors defined in it. You could either try deleting it, or find the history and revert it.

Comment: I know , but it was created that way , and that is the question , why it was created that way ... @WaynePhipps

Comment: what history ? i said it's a new project , the file was created that way ... @Aaron

Comment: I would try creating a new/empty project to see if the issue persists

Comment: as said in the question , the issue persists in any new project .. even after clearing the cache of android and gradle ...@WaynePhipps

Comment: @AmmarMMashfj have you tried re-installing both Android Studio and Gradle?

Comment: if the issue persists in another project , then check is there any updates available for android studio ?

Comment: It's a bug in Android Studio, if you search recent questions with the same error message...

Comment: Anyway i did submit this to Google ... the only questions i found was 24 hours old ... And no one seem to know what is going on in this matter ...@cricket_007

Comment: I'm not following the bug tracker for Studio, but it's been happening for a while https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=colors.xml+document+structures+must+start+and+end+within+the+same+entity&tab=newest

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119838399

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps your problem will be solved:-

1. Close the Android Studio.
2. Go to:
   C:\users\your_user_name\.AndroidStudio3.4\system\caches
3. Delete the caches folder.
4. Go to:
   C:\Users\your_user_name\.gradle\caches
5. Delete this caches folder also.
6. Now you can start your Android Studio and start working.

Your Problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you got that color xml but that's definitely not a color xml file.

A color.xml file looks like below image

[image]

Copy below code to your color.xml file to solve your error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="your_color">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: My question is about how the file got created that way ...not for how to fix this file in particular ... As i said it's not the only file ...

Comment: @AmmarMMashfj it was bug in android studio that's why it's showing file that way.

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi Do you have any official link about this bug ?

Comment: I'v  faced that same issue last year. My java code was in xml form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm literally facing the same issue, did you somehow managed to resolve it?

I though I've been getting this error after invalidating cache and restart Android Studio but it seems to be some kind of different bug from IDE itself.

Comment: nope , no Answer yet , anyhow I've submitted the bug to google issuetracker.google.com/issues/119838399

Comment: droid version 3.2 is too messed up to resolve unexpected bugs at uncertain times, upgraded to Studio version 3.4 Canary 6 till they make previous versions stable or might stick up to it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be which browser you got the install file from. (This answer also appears at [colors.xml: Error: Unsupported type 'component' (Android studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892088/colors-xml-error-unsupported-type-component-android-studio/54430022))

I just had a student with the same problem (version 3.3 now), and it appears to have been fixed by having him install from a file downloaded with Chrome rather than with Edge. Did you originally install with an install file obtained using Edge?

Comment: Downloaded ? I made the project using Android studio !

Comment: I mean when you downloaded Android Studio. Something appears to go wrong in the installation process that mucks up new projects created by Android Studio afterward.

Answer (score 0):

I was just facing the same issue, an incomplete color.xml is generated which causes the build error, just create a new helloworld app project.

What I have done is deleting both the .AndroidStudio3.2 and .android folder in the window's user folder, and then the strange issue has gone...

Looks like a stange IDE bug...