# After creating a project: resource compilation failed

Tags: android

I just started a project and i get this error thrown out:

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\manol\Documents\_docs\programacion\android\MentalPower\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Command: C:\Users\manol\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\3f3056168861575e0d5562b5a9598ddf\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\manol\Documents\_docs\programacion\android\MentalPower\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\manol\Documents\_docs\programacion\android\MentalPower\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

The project is clean, just created it with the default options. The only changes that I did were on the colors.xml file, because it was throwing some errors (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892088/colors-xml-error-unsupported-type-component-android-studio) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875744/error-on-first-build-after-creating-a-project-xml-document-structures-must-star))

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: can you share the code of `ic_launcher_round.xml`?

Comment: Whick API are you targeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error stated in the log is about the file `ic_launcher_round.xml` in `res\mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder.  
If as you said this is a new project then it should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```